# How to make gif images to fit WebView on Android

Tags: android, image, webview, gif

I'm using webview to display gif images, but the problem is, the webview windows doesn't fit the width of gif, there's always some blank space to the right of the gif.

Right now I have to manually set the width and try to keep the width of my gifs, but it's strange that the height always fit the gifs

```
        int w = 115;//image.getWidth();
        LayoutParams lp = holder.wv.getLayoutParams();    
        lp.width= (int) (w * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        holder.wv.setLayoutParams(lp); 

        holder.wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + text.substring(1, text.length()-1) + ".gif");
        holder.wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Webview in xml layout

```
   <WebView
      android:id="@+id/wv"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_margin="2sp"
      android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
      android:visibility="gone"/>
```

There is nothing wrong with the gifs, they don't have the trailing white space

Here is what it looks like on the device

[image]

here is the original gif

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually edit the gif sizes so it fits the window, not a smart way to do but it was the only solution

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to wrap gif in HTML and scale it using CSS:

```
String gif_url = "file:///android_asset/" + text.substring(1, text.length()-1) + ".gif";
String html = "<html><body><img style=\"width: 100%\" src=\"" + gif_url + "\"></body></html>";
holder.wv.loadData(html);
```